# Serialization of Option / None by BinaryFormatter throws ArgumentNullException using F#

Tags: serialization, f#, option-type, binaryformatter

How do I serialize None in F#? The following code throws an `System.ArgumentNullException: Object Graph cannot be null.` error:

```
let f = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
let m = System.IO.MemoryStream()
f.Serialize (m, None)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For some performance reasons, the compiler often will make `None = null`.  I think the best solution is then to wrap the whole thing in an extra layer of Option

like this

```
let f = System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter()
let m = System.IO.MemoryStream()
f.Serialize (m,Some( None))
```

Then you just remove that extra `Some` when you deserialize

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different `serializer`, like `NetDataContractSerializer`. From what I know `BinaryFormatter` is being considered as legacy and has a few other issues too, for instance [this](http://fpish.net/topic/Some/0/59723).

Comment: Good point! I have changed to `NetDataContractSerializer` and None works again ;) Thanks

Comment: I have tested NetDataContractSerializer and the overall performance of my app went down by ca. 30 %. So it seems that I will have to stay with BinaryFormatter due to performance reasons...

Comment: From my tests I have discovered that the performance characteristics of NDC vs BF vary, depending on the structure of the object graph you are trying to serialize. NDC is in principle (but not always!) slower than BF and also produces a larger serialization (about 10x larger, since it uses xml). NDC is however more robust than BF, but may fail in some cases (for instance, very large lists produce stack overflows). You could go for a hybrid approach, for instance handling BinaryFormatter exceptions by calling NDC to the task.